# Uncaught TypeError: e.plugins.wplink.close is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Actualmente tengo un inconveniente con Wordpress, especialmente con la parte administrativa donde cada vez que presiono un botón para guardar un contenido (Sea enlace, imagen, texto... etc) no hace nada, ninguna acción y se dispara el mensaje en la consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.plugins.wplink.close is not a function
```

Reemplacé todos los archivos de Wordpress tanto del root como de la carpeta wp-admin sin éxito. Adjunto una imagen para ilustrar mejor el error:

[image: Error e.plugins.wplink.close is not a function]